# Unable to use DB Alias in SQL Server 2014 SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've been attempting to add a alias in Sql Server Configuration Manager on my local dev box. I've added the Aliases entry under `SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration` and `SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration (32 bit)`  I've added it using port 1437

[image]

TCP/IP has been enabled for database instance the TCP/IP Properties.  The properties on TCP/IP is set to ListenAll = True

[image]

In the Ip Addresses Tab I have TCP dynamic ports to 0 and TCP Port to port 1437
I've restarted every SQL service imaginable

[image]

But when using the Alias in SSMS I get the following error

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the error is talking about `Named Pipes`, not `TCP`.

Comment: Named Pipes are enabled my specific sqlserver2014 instance